# OpenCV visual studio 2013 linker error 1104

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have try to configure visual studio 2013 to program using opencv. My OS is 64 bit and I have followed the below steps.I have extracted the opencv to C:.

1. Create a console application.
2. In properties set C/C++ section ->addtional include directories set to  C:\opencv\build\include.
3. In properties set Linker section ->general->Additional Libarary directories set to  C:\opencv\build\include\x64\vc12\lib
4. Then In Linker->input->Additional Dependencies I add following

   ***opencv_calib3d249d.lib
   opencv_contrib249d.lib
   opencv_core249d.lib
   opencv_features2d249d.lib
   opencv_flann249d.lib
   opencv_gpu249d.lib
   opencv_highgui249d.lib
   opencv_imgproc249d.lib
   opencv_legacy249d.lib
   opencv_ml249d.lib
   opencv_nonfree249d.lib
   opencv_ocl249d
   opencv_objdetect249d.lib
   opencv_photo249d.lib
   opencv_stitching249d.lib
   opencv_superres249d.lib
   opencv_ts249d.lib
   opencv_video249d.lib
   opencv_videostab249d.lib***

these are the names of the file in my C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib folder(there are two versions opencv_calib3d249d and opencv_calib3d249(without d at end))

and then I add following code to my cpp file and try to run.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    Mat img = imread("galpatha.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

    if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
    imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

    waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

it gives me the error

***Error    1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d249d.lib'    c:\Users\Kasun\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenCV_test\OpenCV_test\LINK   OpenCV_test***

Comment: I usually disable precompile header at the beginning..guess it is not the reason

Comment: Can not open means either the lib is corrupt, you don't have the path to the .libs in your linker search paths, or you are mixing 32 and 64 bit in the same application.

Comment: @drescherjm I have changed the Linker ->general->Additional Libarary directories to C:\opencv\build\include\x86\vc12\..but still the same error. I am not sure it is corrupt..

Comment: Are you adding the `include` folder as a library folder? Ouch! Try to use `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib` instead.

Comment: ***these are the names of the file in my C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib folder(there are two versions opencv_calib3d249d and opencv_calib3d249(without d at end))*** I would turn off the hide extensions for known file types in your folder settings. That way you will see the actual extension of your .lib files and tell them apart from files of the same name with different extensions like .dll, .lib, .def and .exp.

Comment: @karlphillip sorry.... C/C++ section ->addtional include Directories set to C:\opencv\build\include. Now i still the same problem..please guys help me..

Comment: It's extremely hard to help given the amount of information that you have posted.

Comment: @drescherjm what else you want..this is all i have done...I followed the here is the link i follow http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html